# retrieving the :id of a given show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I want to add an RSVP button to an Event view. For the RSVP controller, how do I retrieve the id of the Event that the view of which the user has opened, with a check that it is indeed an Event view? Should I create a private method like `current_event` in the application controller?

```
class RsvpsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @rsvp = Rsvp.new(rsvp_params)
    #@rsvp.event_id = ???
  end
end
```

UPDATE with additional info

my models looks like this

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :events, through: :rsvps
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You really haven't provided enough information about your application. How does an event relate to a RSVP. I'm going to make a few assumptions, but think that it will help you overall. Let's say your application will have many Events. An Event has many RSVP and a RSVP belongs to an event.

Typically, you will have something like this within your routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    resources :rsvps
  end
end
```

If you run `rake routes`, you may see something like this

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
    event_rsvps GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)          rsvps#index
                POST   /events/:event_id/rsvps(.:format)          rsvps#create
 new_event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/new(.:format)      rsvps#new
edit_event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id/edit(.:format) rsvps#edit
     event_rsvp GET    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)      rsvps#show
                PATCH  /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)      rsvps#update
                PUT    /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)      rsvps#update
                DELETE /events/:event_id/rsvps/:id(.:format)      rsvps#destroy
```

So your `button` should point to the `rsvps#new` controller and action. Once your user submits the form, it will call the `rsvps` controller and the `create` action.

From here, you can access your `event` with something like `@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])`

Since an `event` `has_many :rsvps` and a `rsvp` `belongs_to :event`, you can create your `rsvp` with something like
    def create
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      @rsvp = @event.rsvps.create(rsvp_params) # strong params

```
  if @rsvp.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Bonus tip: Within your RSVP's form, you will need to change it to something like this since we have nested RSVP under Events.

```
<%= form_for [@event, @rsvp] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for your response! you have the right idea. RSVP is a join between a User and an Event. I added models in the OP. also, there are two ways a User can RSVP, there are two boolean columns `:attending` and `:interested`, like in Facebook.

Comment: as I understand it, the rsvp resource goes needs to be within the user resource, not event. I already have had someone help me here https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/53qmf8/help_making_rsvp_buttons/ , retrieving the event_id for the Rsvp controller was the only missing part of the puzzle.